# If statement check for a string start with a specific number

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I wanted to check if the data begins with `"01"` (meaning it's a phone number) and I wanted to add `"60"` in front of the phone number and replace the dash inside the string to nothing.

I get this error in this line `if Field Like "01*" Then`

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0023'
>
> Sub or Function not defined

Hope someone may be able to tell me what's wrong.

```
<%Option Explicit%>
<%
Dim strConn, strScriptName,strSQL

strConn = Application("eDSNSMS")

strSQL = Request.querystring("SQL")

sub Write_CSV_From_Recordset(RS)
  if RS.EOF then
        exit sub
    end if

    dim RX
    set RX = new RegExp
        RX.Pattern = "\r|\n|,|"""

    dim i
    dim Field
    dim Separator

    do until RS.EOF
        Separator = ""
        for i = 0 to RS.Fields.Count - 1
            Field = RS.Fields(i).Value & ""
            if RX.Test(Field) then
                Field = """" & Replace(Field, """", """""") & """"
            end if
            if Field Like "01*" Then
                Field = "60" + Field
                Field = """" & Replace(Field, "-", "") & """"
            end if
            Response.Write Separator & Field
            Separator = ","
        next
        Response.Write vbNewLine
        RS.MoveNext
    loop
end sub
    
Dim objRS, objConn

set objConn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.ConnectionString = strConn
objConn.Open
set objRS = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
objRS.Open strSQL, strConn, 0, 1

Write_CSV_From_Recordset objRS
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.csv"
%>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the execution of your code in the debugger to identify the line that generates the runtime error?

Comment: @VirtualMichael yes, line -->
if RX.Test(Field) Like "01*" Then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript does not have the `Like` operator found in VBA and VB6. You'll have to test your string using other methods.

For example, you could change:

```
if Field Like "01*" Then
```

To:

```
If Left(Field, 2) = "01" Then
```

Also, you should use `&` to concatenate strings, especially when dealing with values that could be treated as numeric, as you are here:

```
Field = "60" + Field
```

Otherwise you run the risk of *summing* instead of *concatenating*.